# Identical strings don't match in python - an issue with spaces (leading/trailing spaces already removed)

Tags: python, pandas

For one particular entry in a Pandas dataframe, I'm finding that two seemingly identical text fields do not match. I have stripped leading/trailing spaces from both text fields. I have run the following code to investigate the issue:

```
import difflib
print(dst_rows.loc[779,['old_description']]==fee.old_description)
a = dst_rows.loc[779,['old_description']].values[0]
b = fee.old_description
print(a==b)
print(type(a))
print(type(b))
print('|',a,'|')
print('|',b,'|')
print('\n'.join(difflib.ndiff([a], [b])))
```

This was the outcome:

```
old_description    False
Name: 779, dtype: bool
False
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
| Mgmt fees 1Q 2016 + expenses |
| Mgmt fees 1Q 2016 + expenses |
- Mgmt fees 1Q 2016 + expenses
?     ^    ^  ^    ^ ^

+ Mgmt fees 1Q 2016 + expenses
?     ^    ^  ^    ^ ^
```

What could the issue be here? How are the spaces different between the two strings?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try comparing using a.strip()==b.strip(). there might be leading/trailing to the string you cant see.

Comment: If you print the characters in the string, what do you get? There could be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: If that doesn't help, try to compare the `ord()` of each individual character pair until you find a pair where they are different.

Comment: However, a copy/paste of the strings in your question indicates that they are in fact identical.  Demo: https://ideone.com/w5UBAK Maybe [edit] to provide the _actual_ output from your Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because one string contained non-breaking spaces (unicode = 160) while the other contained a regular space (unicode = 32).

Answer (score 1):

After you've assigned *a* and *b* add the following code:

```
for i, (_s1, _s2) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    if ord(*_s1) != ord(*_s2):
        print(f'Strings differ at offset {i}')
```